# DB lib to convert classes into a scheme and auto generate some queries?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

Hey i am looking for a lib that can take the class below and generate these two tables with a reference/foreign key and allow me to tweak the default logic. Like below, unless i specify otherwise when i do sqlClass.Insert(imglist) it will not create another entry for user_id but try to find an existing one in the database.

```
    class image_list
    {
        public PK id;
        [InsertOrSelect]
        public name_list user_id;
        public long pic_id;
        public string link;
    }
    class name_list
    {
        public PK id;
        public UniqueString username;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you design your tables using the LINQ-to-SQL ORM you can use the generated `DataContext` object to create a database containing the schema you designed. The method is called 
[DataContext.CreateDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx)

Comment: sounds like i can get the schema but can not get the queries with LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: If you mean also to automatically create stored procedures, then no. But if not, what do you mean by queries? LINQ-to-SQL doesn't use queries explicitly, you simply access properties (which may refer to foreign-key records) and the query provider fetches them for you transparently.

Comment: interesting, what happens when i write imglist.user_id = new name_list(); imglist.user_id.username = "username1"; I dont think linq to sql will insert/write the data until i ask it too? (I am thinking about incomplete class data and not null values). How would i insert imglist and would it automatically try to insert user_id since it is a reference? Will it try to find if that user exist (by searching the unique string username since it is set and PK id isnt)?

Comment: LINQ to SQL handles that just fine. It was designed for all these scenarios. But you need to read about it.